# Boolean unique dice

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I have a dice class that rolls random numbers from 1-6. I want to create another class that implements checking of all numbers and stops rolling when all unique numbers are rolled once. Not sure how I would use the getFace and boolean method. Thinking of every number starting at false and outcomes true once number appears.

```
public class Die {

public final int MAX = 6; //max 6
private int faceValue; //current value showing on die

//constructor
public Die() {
   faceValue = 1;
   }

public int roll(){
  faceValue = (int)(Math.random()*MAX)+1;
  return faceValue;
  }

public void setFaceValue(int value){
  if(value> 0 && value <=MAX)
     faceValue=value;
  }

public int getFaceValue(){
  return faceValue;
  }

public String toString(){
  String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);
  return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: May start with a `Set` or `List` filled with the unique numbers.  Use `getFaceValue` to remove the value from the `List`, keep rolling until it's empty

Comment: Add face values to a set and when the set size is 6 stop rolling. In roll call setFaceValue add the facevalue to the set. Create a boolean method to check size of the Set and return true or false.

Comment: Havent learned set, its just like a list?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//Add 1-6
for(int i = 1;i < 7;i++){
    numList.Add(i);
}
Die dice = new Die();
While(numList.size() != 0){
   int rolled = dice.roll();
   ArrayList.remove(rolled);
}
```

I assume the code goes something like that. Haven't touch java for a bit.

Comment: how would I test it with another test class? just create a dice object and dice.roll?

Comment: @WickdLotus you should be able to run this in the main method. Like     public static void main(string[] args){//code here and some writeline}

Comment: Still learning about classes I gotta create a instance of this and test it in another class, putting that all in a public void perhaps?

Comment: yea i think that would be possible in another class method but you still have to call the method somewhere probably in the main method. You are able to create the instance for testing purposes in this current class main method and running it.

Answer (score 0):

Logic:
Create a set S. Keep rolling and adding the outcome to that set. Stop when the size of the set is 6. (Set contains unique elements only.)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Die die = new Die();
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        int outcome = 0;

        //Keep rolling until set size is 6.
        while(set.size() != 6) {
            outcome = die.roll();
            set.add(outcome);
        }

        System.out.println(set);

    }

}

class Die {

    public final int MAX = 6; //max 6
    private int faceValue; //current value showing on die

    //constructor
    public Die() {
        faceValue = 1;
    }

    public int roll(){
        faceValue = (int)(Math.random()*MAX)+1;
        return faceValue;
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int value){
        if(value> 0 && value <=MAX)
            faceValue=value;
    }

    public int getFaceValue(){
        return faceValue;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = Integer.toString(faceValue);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense but I haven't learn `hash sets` would an arraylist be similar ?

Comment: Since ArrayList allows duplicates, you can check if the list already contains "outcome". If not, add it to the list. Rest of the code would remain the same.